# Binding WPF combobox to a user settings property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I've a combobox in WPF with 4 static values in it:

```
<ComboBox 
      SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                              Path=KeyModifier, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ComboBoxItem>Alt</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Shift</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Ctrl</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>Win</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

I want to connect the selected value of this combobox with a simple string property in the user settings. That works half way: The selected value is perfectly written to Settings.Default.KeyModifier ... But after restarting the application the selected value of the combobox is not set ... despite that all other controls (Edits, Checkboxes) binded the same way on other properties are set correctly.

Is there some mystery on filling a combobox with values from a binded property?

Or do I have to do the whole selection process on startup manually in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't add strings, but ComboBoxItems to your ComboBox, you would also have to set its `SelectedValuePath` property:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                                  Path=KeyModifier, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBoxItem>Alt</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Shift</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Ctrl</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Win</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Alternatively add strings to the ComboBox, and use `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
...
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
                                 Path=KeyModifier, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <sys:String>Alt</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Shift</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Ctrl</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Win</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

---

Note also that since WPF 4.5 you may write the Binding like this:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=(properties:Settings.Default).KeyModifier, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: The SelectedValuePath made it :-)

Comment: Better just add strings instead of ComboBoxItems

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved the settings after you change the values? `Settings.Default.Save()`

Comment: Yes ... the selected value appears in the user.config